# windows batch's for /f

Tags: variables, for-loop, cmd

i encountred a really annoying problem. i have this file to proccess (.fil):

```
 Babchuk\Bianca\13 Stratford\Sun City West\AZ\Professor
 Babchuk\Deana\12 View\Thousand Oaks\CA\Housewife
 Babchuk\Nicholas\13 Stratford\Sun City West\AZ\Professor
```

i need to create a separate file for each state, state=fifth field (file for the two "AZ" lines and a file for the single "CA" line). in the end, i need to have 2 files: AZ.txt and CA.txt .
each file contains every line that included the file's state.

i came up with this batch, but it won't work. it just creates one nameless file, contatins many lines of "ECHO is off.".

```
for /f "delims=\ tokens=*" %%a IN (c:\windosbk\forf\sortedPx.txt) DO (
    set line=%%a
    for /f "delims=\ tokens=5" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
        set state=%%b
    )
    echo %line%>>%state%.txt
)
pause
```

just to make sure it is clear, the result should be 2 new files:

AZ.txt:

```
Babchuk\Bianca\13 Stratford\Sun City West\AZ\Professor
Babchuk\Nicholas\13 Stratford\Sun City West\AZ\Professor
```

CA.txt:

```
Babchuk\Deana\12 View\Thousand Oaks\CA\Housewife**
```

Comment: There are multiple command processors. Are you using the standard `cmd.exe`?

Comment: do you have to use a dos batch ? unix tools like 'awk' are better at this kind of stuff.

Comment: i think it is the standard cmd, how can i be sure?

Comment: and yea... i must use windows batch

Comment: If you weren't then you'd probably know, but might have forgotten to say. Have you tried constructs like square brackets around the variable names, such as `%[state]`?

Comment: no i have'nt. what do the square brackets do?

Comment: you mean like that: echo %line%>>%[state].txt?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for your sample file:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\windosbk\forf\sortedPx.txt") do (
   for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~pa\.") do >>"%%~nxb.txt" echo %%a
)
```

Comment: +1: That was clever to use FOR variable modifiers instead of tokens. I think you want `"%%~nb.txt"` instead of `"%%~nxb"`. The output files are missing the .txt extension.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks for spotting that Dave.  The `nxb` is used for occasions where the folder has a period, perhaps applicable when future readers may try it.  In this case the added x doesn't affect it.

Comment: Sorry but im not familiar with this %%~pa thing... Can somebody please name this technique for me so ill be able to google it? Or maybe explain a little?

Comment: Read about the for modifiers on the last page of `FOR /?`

Comment: Can you just tell me why the delims part was changed to ""? I mean, the seperator in the file is "/"

Comment: The technique used normally gets the end of the string, or the part up to the last "\". I used it to extract the part up to the last "\" and then extracted the state name alone.  `"delims="` in both `for` commands is required to get the entire line and while `tokens=*` often works to get the whole line, it does strip leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't try to use the `state` or `line` variables, so if they were important to you for another reason then you'll have to put them back in, but this produces the desired output files when given your sample input file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (input.fil) DO (
    echo %%a
    for /f "delims=\ tokens=5" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
        echo %%a >>%%b.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: you were faster. You don't need `delims` in the first line

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. I normally use TCC myself, which has far more powerful string handling, so didn't appreciate what that bit was, and it worked if I left it in...

Comment: I tried what you offerred, echo %%a>>%%b.txt, at first and still got the same "echo is off" result. The variables were just for debugging actually...